# Conditional mean square convergence and consistency

Tags: statistical-inference, regression, nonparametric-statistics

Let $\{(Y_i,X_i)\}$ be i.i.d. random pairs that satisfies
$$Y_i=m(X_i)+e_i, \;\; \mathsf{E}(e_i|X_i)=0, \ i\in\{1,\dotsc,n\}.$$
Let $\hat m(x)$ be an estimator of $m(x)$ at point $x$ and $\boldsymbol{X}=(X_1,\dotsc, X_n)$. If we know the conditional bias and variance converges to zero in probability:
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Bias}(\hat m(X)|\boldsymbol{X})&=o_p(1),\\
\operatorname{Var}(\hat m(X)|\boldsymbol{X})&=o_p(1),
\end{align}
then can we say something about the consistency (convergence in probability) of $\hat m(\cdot)$?

*I'm aware that if $\hat m(x)$ converges in the (unconditional) mean square sense to $m(x)$, then Markov's inequality would imply convergence in probability.

**In my case $\hat m$ is the local linear estimator.

Comment: it would be hard to prove anything without assumptions on your random variables